# How to call a method when a particular activity is finished

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building an app where I need to determine if the user is online or offline using Firebase Authentication and Realtime Database. When the user signs out from the app and is directed to the Sign in page I want to determine the user's status.

I am using AuthStateListeners to monitor user's state. I have added the auth state listener at `onCreate()` method of my Home activity and I have removed the auth listener at `onDestroy()` but the app changes the user's status to offline only when the app is clear from the multitasking tray and not when the Home activity finishes.

Comment: You can override onDestroy method I think..

Comment: Sounds like a case for ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.

Comment: When I am overriding onDestroy method its changing the status to offline only when the user clears the app from the multitasking tray

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //call you function here
    }
```

This is called just before activity is finished refer android activity lifecycle for more detail [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: I tried overriding onDetroy() method but it turns out if the user clear the app from the multitasking tray only then the status changes to offline and not if the user sign out.

Comment: @JaiKrishnanPillai If this answer helped you please accept this answer like this i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Answer (score 0):

You can have field for user status in your database and change it's value according to user behavior.

Example:
In your MainActivity or after he logged in set user's status as online

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().mDataBaseRef
.child(USER_REF_NAME).child(USER_STATUS_CHILD_NAME).setValue("online");
```

and when the user clicks on signout button call this

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().mDataBaseRef
.child(USER_REF_NAME).child(USER_STATUS_CHILD_NAME).setValue("offline");
```

for more info check **Managing Presence** section in [this article](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html)
And if you want to build something more advanced check this [Firebase Blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html).

Comment: The problem here is when the user clicks the sign out button he is signed out from firebase authentication and can no longer access the database since my database rules requires users to be authenticated.
and one of the child of the database is the Firebase UID which the app can only access when the user is signed in.
I tried another way around by using 'FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().myDatabase().child("Users").child(user_id).child("Status").onDisconnect().setValue("offline");' but this is also not working

Comment: you can call the above code exactly before you call FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

Answer (score 0):

call finish() when user clicks sign out and override onDestroy() method

```
void signOut{
 //yourCode
 finish()
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //call you function here
}
```